# Powershell Excel add ConditionalFormatting

Tags: excel, powershell, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to add some ConditionalFormatting to a specific cell in Excel via powershell.
If I use the example code from [powershellgallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/5.4.4/Content/AddConditionalFormatting.ps1) I'm getting errors (in Dutch):

> De waarde valt niet binnen het verwachte bereik.

Translated: *"the value isn't in the expected range"*

In the end I was hoping for a ConditionalFormat (pseudo-code):
If value in specific cell isn't 700 (`$basevalue`) then paint cell red.

What am I doing wrong and how can I do this correctly?

```
function Excel_new {
    $object = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
    $object | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name FullQuit -Value {Excel_FullQuit}
    $object
}

function Excel_FullQuit {
    while ( $this.Workbooks.Count -gt 0 ) {
        $this.Workbooks.Item(1).Close()
    }
    $this.Quit()
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($this)
    [System.GC]::Collect()
    [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    Stop-Process -processname EXCEL
}

$basevalue = 700

$Excel = Excel_new
$Excel.Visible = $true
$Excel.displayalerts = $false
$Excel_wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()
$Excel_ws = $Excel_wb.Worksheets.Add()
$Excel_ws.Name = "WS_sheet_template"
$Excel_ws.activate()
#Add-ConditionalFormatting $Excel_ws.Cells["B:B"] GreaterThan $basevalue #-Fore Red -Stop -Pri 1 
Add-ConditionalFormatting $Excel_ws.Cells.Item( 3 , 3 ) GreaterThan $basevalue -Fore Red -Stop -Pri 1  
$Excel_ws.Cells.Item( 3 , 3 ) = 40
$Excel.FullQuit()
```

-Edit :

I've managed to make it working , but not in the way I need it to be (I think)
I'm opening the excel-package first in the code below.
In the code above I'm creating the file.....
Is there a way to combine this in 1 flow?
This way I need to save the file first before I'm making condittional formats to it.

```
$path  = "C:\filepath\test.xlsx"
$excel = Open-ExcelPackage  $path
$ws = $excel.Workbook.Worksheets["Blad1"]
Add-ConditionalFormatting -WorkSheet $ws -Address "B2:B9" -RuleType GreaterThan -ConditionValue "100" -ForeGroundColor Red
Close-ExcelPackage $excel –Show
```

Comment: Are you sure of the order for positional parameters ? You should define the parameters like this `-RuleType  GreaterThan` rather than only `GreaterThan`, this avoid errors and is far more readable.

Comment: @CFou true - but even whit the defined parameters i get the same error's :)

Comment: :) same error whit - :
Add-ConditionalFormatting -Worksheet $Excel_wb -Address $Excel_ws.cells["b1:b10"] -RuleType Top -ForegroundColor red -BackgroundColor green -ConditionValue 10

Comment: Try with `-Address "b1:b10"`

Comment: @Theo I've tried but still the same error : "the value isn't in the expected range"